# Inner Join Creates Duplicate Records

Tags: sql

Why does this inner join create duplicates?

```
SELECT 
    AU.sProdCode, AU.sProdName
FROM 
    AllowedUsers AU
INNER JOIN 
    ProdMaster PM ON AU.sProdCode = PM.sProdCode
WHERE
    PM.sProdStatus = 'pending' AND
    AU.sUserCode = 'TM001'
```

How to get rid of the duplicate issue?

**ProdMaster**:

```
sProdCode   sProdName   sProdStatus
-----------------------------------
1001        MyProduct   Pending
```

**AllowedUsers**:

```
sProdCode   sProdName   sUserCode
----------------------------------
1001        MyProduct   TM001
```

My condition

1. If the Product status is Pending (In ProdMaster)
2. User is allowed to view the product (In Allowed User - User code)
3. Show the product code / Product name without duplicate.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` does the trick. (Or, since only select columns from one table, do an ´EXISTS`.)

Comment: "Why this inner join creates duplicates?": because you have a 1:n relationship. "How to get rid of the duplicate issue?": Did you search? This has been asked numerous times before.

Comment: I used distinct and it removes one but another one resides :(

Comment: @Sixthsense That doesn't make any sense.  Show us some data please.

Comment: Yes, I searched google a lot and unable to fix my issue.  Finally approaching SO instead of wasting time.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, Updated the Table Data

Comment: My condition is simple.  If the Product status is Pending (In ProdMaster) and the User is allowed to view the product (In Allowed User - User code) then I need to show the product code/name.

Comment: Please show accurate sample data of the actual problem. You will likely have multiple records with the same `sProdCode` in your tables. And maybe the database type might be important.

Comment: Yes, you are right after further investigation there was some duplicate records in AllowedUsers Table.  Now I assigned primary key for Product Code and User Code to restrict the users uploading duplicate entries.  Thanks for your extended support in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you have duplicate rows, presumably in the second table.

The most efficient approach would be `exists`:

```
SELECT AU.sProdCode, AU.sProdName
FROM AllowedUsers AU
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ProdMaster PM 
              WHERE AU.sProdCode = PM.sProdCode AND PM.sProdStatus = 'pending'
             )
WHERE AU.sUserCode = 'TM001';
```

For best performance, you want indexes on `ProdMaster(sProdCode, sProdStatus)`, and `AllowedUsers(sUserCode, sProdName)`.

If you are still getting duplicates, then you have duplicated in `AllowedUsers`.  In that case, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the distinct as below:

```
SELECT distinct AU.sProdCode,AU.sProdName
FROM AllowedUsers AU
inner JOIN ProdMaster PM
ON AU.sProdCode = PM.sProdCode
where PM.sProdStatus = 'pending' and
AU.sUserCode = 'TM001'
```

And the reason is you would have 1 to many relationship in tables.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what's the output/ issue you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I developed a table to simulate custom sort order ( when A-Z, 1-9 is not an option ) when I tried to join 2 elements I got two rows of result, until I grouped inside query then I was able to order

Here is the code sample:

```
select x.thg, 
       x.Business_Capability as BC, 
       x.TotApps
from (
        select [inv].[thg], [inv].[Business_Capability], count(1) as TotApps, 
        **thgO.Srtorder as thgo, bcpO.Srtorder as bcpo**

         FROM [dbo].[cbVcsi] as inv
         inner join **cbSOcat thgO** on   ( thgO.Family = 'thgrp' and thgO.Item = inv.thg )
         inner join **cbSOcat bcpO** on   ( bcpO.Family = 'BizCap' and bcpO.Item = inv.Business_Capability )
         where  [inv].[Business_Capability] not in (  'Automation', 'Testing' ) and [inv].[ParentAppId] = 0
         Group By [inv].[thg], [inv].[Business_Capability], **thgO.Srtorder, bcpO.Srtorder**
) AS x
order by  **x.thgo, x.bcpo**
```